Let A be a 2n-element set. Find the number of pairings of A.
I am having trouble understanding how one of the solutions to this problem works:
Let a pairing of A partition the set into 2-element subsets. Example: a pairing of {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} is {{a, b}, {c,d}, {e, f}, {g, h}}. Let A be a 2n-element set. Find the number of pairings of A.
I understand the first solution, which involves choosing two from 2n, then 2 from 2n-2 and so on, and then dividing by n! Since order doesn’t matter. However, I am having trouble understanding how the second solution works:
Pick an arbitrary element, say x, of A. The number of ways to select x's partner, say y, is 2n-1. Pick an arbitrary element, say z, from 2n-2 elements of A\{x, y}. The number of ways is 2n-3. Continue to get (2n-1)(2n-3)...(5)(3)(1)
I am having trouble understanding how we don’t need to count ways to select the arbitrary element. I would appreciate a more clear explanation.

Rather than "pick an arbitrary element, say x, of A"... reword it to be "Take the least remaining unused element of $A$, call it $x$."  There is always some "least" element according to some canonical ordering of the elements.  If the elements were people, you could do it by age, or by name, or something.  By the fact that there are finitely many elements there necessarily exists some canonical ordering that you can use to your advantage (even if it might not be the same ordering someone else might have picked).  In that sense it is "arbitrary" but it does not affect the overall count.

Because every element will end up having a partner. You could, WLOG, start by finding $1$'s partner, then continuing pairing with the smallest remaining element.
